# Is it possible to have a template that works on multiple categories where the link address contains the specific category?

Tags: categories, templates, archive-template

This question is for a very specific refinement on the use of WordPress template files. The refinement would work similarly to how default archive.php and variants work, but we would like to have a second template that has the same mechanism for querying the desired category through the link address.

The model is a wood site where some people like to browse through the default template style, but others would prefer to just see a list of links.

The goal is to create one template where the category would be passed to the template through the link, instead of having to create a new list template for each category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using a meta field ? That way you can determine which template to use for specific category template.

In your loop just get the current category that you are trying to load:

```
if( have_posts() ) {
while( have_posts() ) {

    the_post();
    $meta_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , 'meta-field', true );

    if($meta_value == 'template1') { 
         //I prefer using this method. Create folder templates with file content-template1.php where you can design your content. That way it is way more clear.
         get_template_part('templates/content','template1');
         // or you can use this method
         the_title();
    }

}

// Very Important
wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: This may not be precisely the answer, but I think an adaptation will work.